# What's the meaning of :[]

Tags: ruby, ruby-on-rails-3

I'm new to ruby on rails, there's a code something like:

```
person_map.try(:[], :name)
```

What's the meanning of :[] here?

Comment: Note: Ruby is a case-sensitive language and capital letters have specific meaning in terms of syntax. Variables and method names should be lower-case letters. Capitals indicate constants of the form  `ClassName` or `CONSTANT_NAME`.

Answer (score 5):

`:[]` is a symbol. In the context of your line of code, it represents the name of the method which should be `try`ed.

You should check the documentation of [`try`](https://api.rubyonrails.org/classes/Object.html#method-i-try) to better understand that line of code. It's basically equal to `personMap[:name]` while making sure that no exception will be raised if `personMap` does not have a `[]` method (e.g if `personMap` is nil).

Comment: “if personMap does not have a `[]` method”—technically this is incorrect. `#try` is explicitly defined on `NilClass`, not on `Object` and `5.try :[]` would still raise.

Comment: @AlekseiMatiushkin Rails defines a `try` method for `Object`, check the link in the answer.

Answer (score 1):

First of all, you have to know that in Ruby you might specify a method name by its symbol, which let's you do metaprogramming.

For example both these lines of ruby do the same thing:

```
Time.now
Time.send(:now)
```

Obviously the second one is longer but it lets you specify the method name based on a variable. Here is a silly example:

```
user.send( age>=18 ? :access : :goback)
```

Depending on the `age` being above 18 or not, a different method will be called on `user`. Now like I said it is a silly example that can be achieved differently. But the method name can also be passed as a string which unlocks a lot of possibilities because strings can be composed.

Anyway in your case the method `try` receives another method name as an argument. If you are familiar with javascript, this is more or less what you would do when you give a function name without the parentheses. But in Ruby you can call a method without the parentheses, so it wouldn't work. It is not exactly similar because in javascript you pass a variable containing this exact function, but the end purpose is often the same.

This leads me to the other thing that is different in Ruby from most other languages. Yes, `[]` is a method name. Something to note is that to add expressiveness, Ruby lets us create method names with `?` or `!` at the end. Nothing is enforced but the convention is that method names ending with `?` return `true` or `false`. And method names ending with `!` are changing the original object as opposed to the version without it.

```
new_hash = hash1.merge(hash2) # This returns a completely new object  
hash1.merge!(hash2) # This merges hash2 into hash1
                    # Therefore hash1 is affected
```

And then to be even more expressive you can define a few methods that are usually infix operators like `*`, `==`, `>=`, `<` or other operators like `[]` and again there is a convention but you can make it behave the way you want.

You can even call these methods the regular method way:

```
age == 13
# is exactly like
age.==(13)

array[3]
# is exactly like
array.[](3)
```

It obviously looks bizarre like that but it is at the core of ruby to give conveniency without sacrificing consistency. Essentially operators ARE methods and should be treated the same way. They are probably turned into method calls in the abstract syntax tree.

Being able to redefine these allows ruby to do things like these:

```
"h" * 5 # "hhhhh"
"username:password"[/\A[a-z]+/i]
```

By the way `:[]=` is also a method name with 2 arguments:

```
object[key] = "value"
# is exactly like
object.[]=(key, "value")
```

On any class, you could define these methods:

```
class Database

  # ...

  def [](id)
    @connection.find_by_id(id)
  end

  def []=(id, data)
    @connection.save(id, data)
  end
end
```

Again a silly example but it's to show that by convention, these methods are getters and setters for some kind of list of things, not necessarily an Array or Hash. It can also be for defining proxy for an underlying Array or Hash. As long as you can define these, the world is your oyster if you think it's going to be more expressive.

Comment: Parameter to `send` doesn't have to be a symbol. Can be a string too. This can simplify your answer somewhat.

Comment: @SergioTulentsev you're right I will edit my answer. I remember it not being the case before ruby 1.9 or something and I kept the habit of always making sure it is a symbol.